# select label for jquery selector

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-2

```
<%: Html.CompleteEditorFor(m => m.PetSitterRestrictionPermission.OffLimitAreas)%>
```

Above generated code is as below

```
<label for="PetSitterRestrictionPermission_OffLimitAreas">Off-limit areas</label>
<input id="PetSitterRestrictionPermission_OffLimitAreas" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="area" name="PetSitterRestrictionPermission.OffLimitAreas" style="display: none;">
<span id="PetSitterRestrictionPermission_OffLimitAreas_validationMessage" class="field-validation-message"></span>
```

How to select `label` from above code for give some jquery effect (as a selector) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use..

```
$('label')  // to select all label

$('label[for="PetSitterRestrictionPermission_OffLimitAreas"]') //to select particular label by for..
```

example..

```
$('label').hide();  //hides all label
$('label[for="PetSitterRestrictionPermission_OffLimitAreas"]').show('slow'). //for particualr level with effect
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
$("label[for='PetSitterRestrictionPermission_OffLimitAreas']").text('what ever you want');
```